# Unable to install Pytorch in Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, pytorch, conda

I'm using the following command to install pytorch in my conda environment.

```
conda install pytorch=0.4.1 cuda90 -c pytorch
```

However, I'm getting the following error

> Solving environment: failed
>
> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from
> current channels:
>
> - pytorch=0.4.1
> - cuda90
>
> Current channels:
>
> - https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/linux-32
> - https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/noarch
> - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/pytorch/linux-32
> - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/pytorch/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-32
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-32

> To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package
> you're looking for, navigate to
>
> ```
> https://anaconda.org
> ```

How can I sort this out?
I have ofcourse installed cuda 9 and nvcc works.

Comment: I trimmed the links since stackoverflow wont allow me to post more than 8 links as I don't have enough points.

Comment: Not all packages and versions available via pip are available via conda packages. conda has some version of pytorch available, but doesn't appear to have 0.4.1. The latest 1.6.0 is available.

Comment: The version you are trying to install is very old, try installing newer version( currently 1.6.0 is the most recent), you can generate install command for conda via pytorch website in the getting started section

Comment: The code that i'm trying is in 0.4.1 :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go directly to the pytorch website and follow the instructions for your setup and it will tell you exactly the command required to install - [pytorch - get started](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/)

For example:

[image]

If you're looking for older versions of PyTorch, the version history and commands to install can be found here - [Installing Previous Versions of PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/)

If this doesn't work for you, your last option is to build from source yourself. Here's the GitHub repo for version 0.4.1 - [pytorch at 0.4.1](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/tree/v0.4.1). The steps to install from source are outlined on the repo [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/tree/v0.4.1#from-source).

Comment: I would like to install version 0.4.1 :(

Comment: Try this: https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/

Comment: I tried ` conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=9.2 -c pytorch` and it throws the same error :(

Comment: Added a further option to answer above outlining building older versions from source.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that it is the version number that is giving the issue. For starters, to specify a particular version, you cannot use '=' sign. If you are particularly looking for the same version your specified, I'd recommend trying pytorch0.4.1 as the package name or else you could grab the latest version by:

```
conda install -c pytorch pytorch
```

You could refer to this site for CUDA:
https://anaconda.org/anaconda/cudatoolkit

or if this is the right one for you, run this command

```
pip3 install pycuda
```

Comment: I tried conda install -c pytorch0.4.1 pytorch and it did not work :(

Comment: Could you try the instructions here and let me know if it works? https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/19457